# Compraing 2 MYSQL tables to find matching data PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my MYSQL database called `Komplektacija` and `pack_to_light`

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eyd35.png)

`komplektacija` table holds the information about Item1, Item2, Item3 ......
`pack_to_light` table holds the information about which Item is assigned to certain devices

What I need to do, is compare both tables and find a device in `pack_to_light` table which has "Item" and "Serial" that matches the "Item" and "Serial" in `komplektacija` table and update Quantity in "pack_to_light" table.

```
For this particular example. I would need to return:
device 1 | Item1 | 12345 | 1
```

I do not have much PHP experience but I believe I would need to use UNION operator in PHP to find matching data. I am trying to understand how to find matching data first, then I worry about updating quantity. Would someone be able to give me a hint

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Currently, this question is unfortunately too broad.

Comment: UNION is part of SQL, not php

Comment: This can all be done in SQL. As you are new to PHP you're not that much at a disadvantage to learn how to do it in MySQL. Start with getting the SELECT working, then change it to an UPDATE

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It works fine with The Impaler suggested script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated UPDATE will do. For example:

```
update pack_of_light p, Komplektacija k
set p.Quantity = k.Quantity
where k.Serial = p.Serial and k.Item = p.Item
```

Result:

```
Device   Item   Serial  Quantity 
-------- ------ ------- -------- 
device1  Item1  12345   1        
device2  Item4  2141    0        
device3  Item6  23241   0
```

You can see a running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cdR4b2HqfayqmjMaii9GYL/0).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the matching data from both of the tables. Im not sure if I can ask for more details on this forum since I mentioned PHP, however I have decided to use python to run the script:

```
def compare_2_tables(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = "UPDATE pack_to_light p, komplektacija k SET p.Quantity = k.Quantity WHERE k.Serial = p.Serial and k.Item = p.Item"
    cur.execute(query)
    myConnection.commit()
    for p.Device,p.Quantity in cur.fetchall() :
        print (Device, Quantity)
        string = Device+"/"+Quantity;
        print (string)
        mqttc.publish(string,quantity)
```

What I am trying to do here, is extract the information about which device was updated and what number of quantity. In case of previous example, I would need to return device1 and 1. I need these two variables in order to send the device1 the right message. Are there anyone with python knowledge who could guide me through that?